# A Sentence ending with 'no more'

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

> They spend good money to get political celebrities but everyone knows that in the end, these actions are about securing an individual's status within the community, **no more**.

-The Indian Express

In what reference 'no more' is used and how it is connected with the sentence. Is it a kind of 'adjunct'?

Comment: Would you understand it better if it ended 'and no more than that'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, Thankyou.I was not able to think it in that way. So it was used in relation with the 'community'?

Comment: It's used in relation to "what these actions are about".

Comment: @KateBunting Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an *adverbial phrase*. Just as adverbs like "definitely" or "approximately" add definition to a statement, "no more" is doing the same in your text.

Consider these examples:

- It costs $100, approximately.
- It costs $100, exactly.
- I will accept $100, no less.
- I can afford $100, no more.

Your text is saying that is just *one reason* why 'they' spend money on celebrities, and *no more than one*.